# Compare typeof class

Tags: c#, .net, typeof

I have an issue:

```
Control controlToGetFocus = this;
if (this.Parent.GetType() == typeof(...))
```

I can't access that class from here since they are from different project and is suppose to be separated.

Is there some way I can do this, maybe some other way around? I did try for `this.Parent.Name` which works fine but my eyes don't like that solution ;)

Comment: Maybe you can check for some common, shared between projects interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
if (this.Parent.GetType().ToString() == "YOURTYPE")
```

UPDATE:

You can create a Common project with types you need to share, and reference this project from any other project.  Then following will work:

```
if (this.Parent is YOURINTERFACETYPE)
```

assuming that Parent object implements YOURINTERFACETYPE

Comment: Not a good recommendation in my opinion, refactoring or obfuscation are likely to break it

Comment: It's not a recommended solution, but that will work for the author.  Otherwise he needs a separate Common project to reference.

Comment: Think this is the best solution for now. Thanks!

Comment: @user2605871 great, but in long term solution look better into Update I've added.  Don't forget to mark the answer :)

Comment: @user2605871 - are you in control of the implementation of the ´Parent´ object? If not, the interface approach is a no-go.

Answer (score 4):

If what you need is checking if ´this.Parent´ is a specific implementation, you should use interfaces instead of the specific types. As you say, your projects are supposed to be separated. But it is quite ok for projects to share common interfaces.

Given an interface like this:

```
public interface IDoStuff { }
```

you can check if Parent implements it like this:

```
if (this.Parent is IDoStuff) { ... }
```

**NOTE**: this approach of course requires that you are in control of the implementation of the instance found in ´Parent´.

**NOTE2**: to clarify, the common interface must be placed in a separate project/assembly that both projects can reference.

Comment: "can't access that class from here since they are from different project and is suppose to be separated. " So Interface is going to b not accessible also.

Comment: @realnero - sure. But both projects can access a third, common project that contains such shared interfaces. That said, are you in control of all projects here? If not, you certainly cannot add the interface to that implementation, and my suggestion will not work for you.

Comment: wasn't note added later? :)

Comment: Ask OP about this, he knows if he has control or not. Why you deleted your comment?

Comment: @realnero - hoho, just realized that I confused you for the OP. Sorry :)